Help moving files but not directories
I have a directory that has 100s of jpg files and about 20 subdirectories. I want to move all of the files out to another directory but leave all the subdirectories.   I found this question and answer that appeared to do exactly what I wanted.
Moving only files, not directories?
That question does not allow me to comment and that is the reason I created this question.
Ordinal folder
/mnt/user/data/media/photos
I want all the individual files in there to move to
/mnt/user/data/media/unsorted_photos
So I ran this command
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name 'exe_*' -exec mv {} /mnt/user/data/media/unsorted_photos \;
It ran for a while and all the files are gone out of the ordinal folder.  However there is no /mnt/user/data/media/unsorted_photos folder with my files.  They are just gone.  There is now a file unsorted_photos with a creation date in 2015.  I have no idea where the files went.  Is there any way to get them back?

You're going to want to stop writing to (possibly unmount?) /mnt/user/data to have any hope of file recovery - for an explanation of what happened see for example command "find ... -exec mv ..." created a file with strange content

If there was no unsorted_photos directory, then what happened is that each file find found, one by one, was moved into place at /mnt/user/data/media/ with that name.  That file will be the last one moved by find.  There may be some data recovery tools you could use to recover the data if you immediately unmount the filesystem and henceforth only mount it read-only until you attempt data recovery.

Thanks.  I have an off site backup so i can just restore.  That sounds easier then going the recovery tool route.

I am glad to hear that you have an offsite backup that you can recover from; that will be a lot easier.  Next time you have an operation like this, I suggest using cp rather than mv, and once you verify the copy is true and correct and all is as you expect, you can re-run the same find using -delete rather than -exec to clean up.
